# How to retract a "Leave Open" vote?

Tags: support

I pressed "Leave Open" by mistake. I actually wanted to close this question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5564995?filter-tags=java

I went to the question itself and voted to close there, since the entry in the review queue wouldn't allow me to change my vote.

However, even though I have voted to close, the summary in the review queue still shows my vote as Leave Open. How can I retract my Leave Open vote?

Comment: In the case of "Leave Open", you can open the question outside the review queue and cast a close vote on it.